# Converting png files into gif file using ios sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, uiimage, cgimageref

I am creating iphone app that take images from library and covert into gif file.
I am successfully created using the below link

http://gist.github.com/mayoff/4969104

Using this code i am able to create gif file. but images quality are changing. some images are grown streched.
 Please any one help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If *you* are writing the app to convert to GIF, then don't you think *you* should figure out the issue. This is a very specific question targeted at your own app that probably won't help anyone else. If you would like to make this a more generic question besides "Help me finish my app", that would be great. Cheers. :-)